# Linear independence of three simple functions (2.9-22)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Why is the following set of three functions linearly independent on an interval $I$ with $x>0$ if $k_2$ can take on any value besides zero and still hold true for a zero sum or that $k_1=k_3$ which suggests linear dependence?

$$y=\{cos(x), sin(x), 1\}$$

The Wronskian for this set of functions is not zero so we know this set is linearly independent:

$$W(y)=cos(x)^2+sin(x)^2=1$$

But when I take a sample point $x=\pi$ for:

$$k_1*cos(x)+k_2*sin(x)+k_3*1=0$$

we have:

$$-k_1*1+k_2*0+k_3*1=0$$

$$-k_1+k_3=0$$

$$k_1=k_3$$

They appear to contradict themselves. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing that for the functions to be linearly dependent you need $\displaystyle \sum_i k_i f_i(x)=0$ to be true *for all* $x$.

So choosing a single $x$ to check is not enough.

If you also looked at $x=\frac\pi2$ you would find $k_2=-k_3$.  If you looked at $x=\frac\pi4$ you would find $k_1+k_2=-\sqrt2k_3$.  Combine these with $k_1=-k_3$ and the only solution is $k_1=k_2=k_3=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the great input. Its a little clearer now.